# Conditional inclination with ようと思ったら

Tags: volitional-form, conditionals

I've started listening to Japanese podcasts more frequently to cultivate my audio comprehension, and I've encountered an expression I am not confident that I understand.

The female broadcaster jokingly asks the male broadcaster what year in the Heisei era they're in...

> F: さって、平成何年でしょうか。
>   M: 「平成何年でしょうか」？そんな風に止めてくださいよ！
>   F: はい。私も、今、そこで調べ**ようと思ったら**ですね？

I know that the basic meaning of the ようと思う construct is "(I) think (I) will X" where "X" is the verb ending in the volitional よう, and my guess would be ようと思ったら means something like "If (I) think (I) will X" or "If (I'm) going to X," so I'm taking this sentence to mean something like "I (should) look into it now if I'm going to, right?"

Comment: Sounds like F has something more to say. 
English is not my strong suit but what she said can be roughly translated as "That's when I thought I would look it up, but..."

Comment: [止]{や}めてくださいよ or [止]{と}めてくださいよ?

Answer (score 1):

It means "I had intended to check it". 
She's saying "I agree. You know, just now, I had intended to check it."

She said 思ったら because the guy stopped her before she managed to check it. If she used 〜と思ったけどね it'd mean the same thing, without the 'being stopped by you' implied.